# print if inclusive dates is already done - php

Tags: php

I am doing an employee leave system and I want to output if the employee's inclusive leave dates is over. This is my code:

```
$count =0;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE inclusive_dates='??'";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $count +=1;
                $mi =$row['id_no'];
                $mo=$row['fullname'];
                $mu =$row['type_of_leave'];
                $me =$row['inclusive_dates'];
```

What will be my sql condition for me to know that the date saved in my database is past. For example the date saved is January 18 to January 22 and the current date is January 19. It will print that the name of that person whose date is not yet past. Sorry for my english

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What will be my sql condition for me to know that the date saved in my database is past. For example the date saved is January 18 to January 22 and the current date is January 19. It will print that the name of that person whose date is not yet past. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it's unclear from your example what `inclusive_dates` contains. Is it a string containing both the start and end date? It would probably work better if you stored start and end dates separately.

Assuming the database columns use a unix timestamp, the simplest way would be to just do a check to see if `time()` (current unix timestamp) is greater than the leave start date and less than the leave end date. As long as you save the start date as say just after midnight 00:00:01 and the end date as right at the end of the day just before midnight (say 23:59:59) then you shouldn't have any problems.

Edit:

```
$currentTime = time();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE leave_start_time > $currentTime
        AND leave_end_time < $currentTime';
```

Comment: ok now I separate the start and end date.. how could I code that? what would be the column that would use a unix timestamp?

Comment: I think it would be best if you had columns called `leave_start_time` and `leave_end_time` (or something similar) - both of these would be INT's that are long enough to store a unix timestamp. The SQL would look something like the edit I made to my answer above.